# Round up instead of down when below zero

Tags: ruby, rounding

It seems Ruby chooses to round negative numbers down instead of closer to zero.

```
-1.5.round
#=>-2
```

Whereas positive numbers work the other way:

```
2.5.round
#=>3
```

How do I round up negative numbers(closer to zero) instead of rounding them down? I'm using ruby version 2.2.2.

Comment: Please list your version of Ruby.

Comment: The first question is why you'd want to do this? There's dozens of rounding methodologies, each with their pros and cons, so knowing your goal here would be ideal. A good rounding function rounds half the numbers up and half down so that it doesn't heavily skew averages or sums.

Comment: @tadman I wish to round up a large number of pairs. I divide the two and then I round the result. However, if the result happens to be negative it rounds down instead of up. It seems illogical to me and I wish to fix it.

Comment: Rounding correctly is a fine art, and there are [many methods to do it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding). Just because it seems illogical does not mean it's the wrong way to do it. I'd make sure you're absolutely certain this is the way you want to go before committing to this irregular form of rounding. It may lead to unpredictable results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
> (-1.5+0.5).floor
=> -1
> (-1.4+0.5).floor
=> -1
> (-1.6+0.5).floor
=> -2
```

Comment: Is there a built-in Ruby method that controls the rounding of a negative number to OP's liking? Is there a gem he could use?

Comment: You could always extend the built-in class with your own `fancy_roundy` method. Using a bias factor, as demonstrated here, is generally how this is approached.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to make some adjusts to round as you want:

```
    def roundy(x)
  x.to_i
  if x<0
    puts (x. + 0.1).round
  else puts x.round
  end
end
```